last submission cannot be restored as the driver code has been updated GeeksForGeeks
As you can see its showing last submission cannot be restored as the driver code has been updated
Issue: Unable to Retrieve Previous Submissions on Geeks for Geeks
I have been practicing Data Structures and Algorithms (DSA) on Geeks for Geeks and have submitted codes earlier. However, I am now facing an issue where I cannot retrieve my previous submissions. The platform displays a message saying, "Last submission cannot be restored as the driver code has been updated."
What I Have Tried:
Checked Submission History: I have checked my profile and submission history but couldn't find a way to access the previous submissions.
Contacted Support: I have raised a query with Geeks for Geeks support, but I haven't received any response yet.
Browser Cache: I attempted to look through my browser's cache and history, hoping to find the submitted code, but had no luck.
Question:
How can I retrieve my previous DSA code submissions on Geeks for Geeks after a driver code update? Is there any other way to access them or any steps I might have missed?
